# Why does this Java do while code create an infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, infinite

I'm trying to figure out why my do while loop leaves me with an infinite loop, there's no way I can progress, even though logically speaking, to me it seems like it should work. Heres the code in question:

```
public void enterData(){ 
        System.out.println("Polish Notation Calculator");
    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter an operation: ");
        oper = input.next().charAt(0);
    }while (oper != '+' || oper != '*' || oper != '/' || oper != '-' || oper != '%');
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        x = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Second number: ");
        y = input.nextDouble();
```

From what I can tell, all this loop says is Do the print and the scan function, while oper is not equal to anything in the quotations. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Your while loop boolean condition is always true.

Comment: Think this through. Perhaps you want to use the `&&` operator ;)

Comment: You are asking the user to input an operation, only to check if they did NOT enter an operation...

Comment: Use `while ("+*/-%".indexOf(oper) == -1);`

Comment: Yes, that is even better. You should put it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your condition is always true. Replace || with &&.

Or you can rewrite is as:

```
while (!(oper == '+' || oper == '*' || oper == '/' || oper == '-' || oper == '%'))
```

which is logically equivalent to:

```
while (oper != '+' && oper != '*' && oper != '/' && oper != '-' && oper != '%')
```

In other words:

```
NOT(A = X || A = Y)
```

is the same as:

```
A != X && B != Y
```

Or you use the KISS principle:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an operation: ");
    oper = input.next().charAt(0);

    if ("+*/-%".indexOf(oper) != -1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you use [decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)):

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter an operation: ");
    oper = input.next().charAt(0);
} while (!isValidOperation(oper));

...

public boolean isValidOperation(char oper) {
    return oper == '+' || oper == '*' || oper == '/' || oper == '-' || oper == '%';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
while (oper != '+' || oper != '*' || oper != '/' || oper != '-' || oper != '%');
```

with

```
while (oper != '+' && oper != '*' && oper != '/' && oper != '-' && oper != '%');
```

At the moment, your condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

For the loop to exit, the operator entered at line

```
oper = input.next().charAt(0);
```

has to be different than `'+', '-', '*', '/'` and `'%'`. If any of these characters is entered, the loop will repeat. Obviously, this is what you are doing.

So, an obvious solution is to replace the `||` operand of the `while` clause with `&&`.

Another solution is to use a `switch` statement, that is a bit more readable (and faster):

```
boolean loop = true;
do {
  System.out.print("Please enter an operation: ");
  oper = input.next().charAt(0);
  switch (oper) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
      loop = false;
      break;
} while (loop);
```

Comment: I don't think being faster will help at all. The delay from user input will far exceed the delay for checking 5 characters.

Comment: What makes you believe the 5-way `switch` is faster than a 5-way equality check?

Comment: The `switch` statement is faster because it only needs 1 lookup to identify the branch to be executed. With an `if` statement, the speed of execution depends on which value matches - e.g., for the 5 values that the code in the question checks, at worst it may need to evaluate 5 values at worst, plus the logical operators `||` or `&&`.

Comment: @PNS You're assuming a jump table lookup into a table that fits all values. That's unlikely to be the case. Since the values range from ASCII 37-47 *(inclusive)*, two(!) range boundary checks are needed before a jump table lookup. So you are comparing performance of (up to) 5 value checks vs. 2 value checks and a table lookup. *On average*, I'd say the 2.5 value checks is faster than 2 value checks + lookup. And you're mistaken when you say that `||` or `&&` takes time, because they just define the code flow and doesn't actually cost anything. Difference is too small to matter though.

Comment: For sparse values, as in this case, you are right. The `||` and `&&` are fast to evaluate, but not free (in the sense that nothing is). I agree that the difference in performance is negligible, across all solutions. :-)

Comment: `||` and `&&` do not get *evaluated*. The generated bytecode is basically 5 different `if` statements with one operator each, not a single `if` statement with nine operators. Try disassembling the code if you don't believe me.

Comment: That's what I meant with "evaluated", the multiple `if`s, hence the comparison with the `switch` statement.